# How to not allow deleting all rows in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple table with 3 columns with classes = "code","description","delete" the column has class "delete" is a checkbox type, and one button with class="savebtn".

I need the following :

When user click save :

1. the Jquery must verify the code column that it has data.
2. If any cell in delete column is checked, Delete that row.
3. If the user checked all cells in delete column alert message that the table must has at least one row , and don't delete the rows.

this is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ko55Lbt3/) but it not working with me.

that what i tried :

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
$(".savebtn").bind("click", function(e){
    $('.savebtn').attr('disabled',true);
    $('.table tbody tr').each(function () {
       $(this).find('.code input').each(function () {
           if ($(this).closest("tr").find(".delete input").is(":checked")  && $('.cf-table-block tbody tr').length >=1){
               $('.delete input :checkbox:checked').closest('tr').remove();
               $('.savebtn').removeAttr('disabled');
           }else if($(this).closest("tr").find(".delete input").is(":checked")  && $('.cf-table-block tbody tr').length <2){
               e.preventDefault();
           }else if($('.delete input').prop('checked')==false && ( $(this).val().length>0)){
               $('.savebtn').removeAttr('disabled');
           }else if ($('.delete input').prop('checked')==false && ( $(this).val().length==0)){
               $(this).attr("placeholder", "Please fill this field");
            }
          });
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: `(index):45 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` - No jQuery reference.

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/ko55Lbt3/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should look at wrapping your table header in `<thead>` and body in `<tbody>`. This will allow you to determine how many rows are relevant to our needs.

It'd be good to then create an array of rows that are checked to be deleted, this can then be compared (via `length`) to the original amount of rows.

Here's an example - I've removed a lot of the logic as the use of an array to store checked rows will help remove the need for a lot of those conditionals.

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ko55Lbt3/3/)

Edit: [Here's a new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko55Lbt3/5/) in which i've added a button for you to clear/populate the last rows value so you can test.

Answer (score 0):

This is updated fiddle of what you are trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/ko55Lbt3/6/

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
$(".savebtn").bind("click", function(e){
$('.savebtn').attr('disabled',true);

 if($(".table tr [type='checkbox']:checked").length >= $('.table   tr').length -1)
 {
 alert("all rows can not be deleted");
 return false;
}

$('.table tr').each(function () {




 $(this).find('.code input').each(function () {



if ($(this).closest("tr").find(".delete input").is(":checked")){
if($(this).val().length > 0)
{
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  $('.savebtn').removeAttr('disabled');
}
else 
{
      $(this).attr("placeholder", "Please fill this field");
    }
    }
 });
 });
 });
 });
```

There are few problem with selectors in your current code which i have corrected.For example "**tbody**" element is no where, the **td** should not have the **type** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with a simple count on each click:

**See in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/z608hg31/)**

```
 $(document).ready(function (){ 

    // on click "Save"
    $(".savebtn").bind("click", function(e){
        $('.savebtn').attr('disabled',true);

        // Delete rows
        $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
            if($(this).prop("checked")){
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });

    // on click a checkbox
    $("input:checkbox").on("click", function(){

        checkboxCount=0;
        $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
            checkboxCount++;
        });

        $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked")){
                checkboxCount--;
            }
        });

        // this is just to see the value in jsFiddle
        $("#console").html(checkboxCount);

        // If there is no checkbox unchecked, disables the Save button and alert.
        if(checkboxCount<1){
            alert("Table must have at least one row!");
            $('.savebtn').attr('disabled',true);
        }else{
            $('.savebtn').attr('disabled',false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/f7ce7dpj/

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table" style="width:100%" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="code">Code</th>
      <th class="description">Description</th>
      <th class="delete">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="code" type="text">1</td>
      <td type="text">aa</td>
      <td class="delete">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="code" type="text">2</td>
      <td type="text">bb</td>
      <td class="delete">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="code" type="text">3</td>
      <td type="text">cc</td>
      <td class="delete">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input class="savebtn" style="width: 65px; font-size: 16px;" type="button" value="Save">
```

**Script:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      // on click "Save"
      $(".savebtn").bind("click", function(e) {
        $('.savebtn').attr('disabled', true);
        var table_rows = $('table tbody').find('tr').length;
        var checked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
        if (checked < table_rows) {
          // Delete rows
          $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
              $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            }
          });
        } else {
          alert("Table must have at least one row!");
        }
        $('.savebtn').attr('disabled', false);
      });
    });
```